# SiteScope URL Monitor Regex

Tags: regex, sitescope

I have a web page which has a html code like this below:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="text-align: center; color:#000080; font-weight: bold; font-size: 14pt; background-color:#B0C4DE;" width="100%">AX1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<!-- /E/ ftacput3 -->
<div style="color:#000080; font-size:11pt; font-weight:bold;">CPU usage as of: 10:05</div><table width="80%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr><td style="text-align:center; color:#D2691E; font-style:italic; font-size:14pt; font-weight:bold;" width="100%" colspan="4">083%</td></tr><tr><td style="background:green; height:25px;" width="70%">&nbsp;</td><td style="background:yellow; height:25px;" width="13%">&nbsp;</td><td style="height:25px;" width="017%">&nbsp;</td></tr></table><br><div><span style="color:#8B4513; font-weight:bold; font-size:11pt;">Recent averages:</span><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1"><tr><td width="23%"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1"><tr><td style="color:#8A2BE2; font-style:italic; font-size:10pt; font-weight:bold;" width="100%" colspan="4">Last 5 minutes </td></tr><tr><td style="text-align:center; color:#8A2BE2; font-style:italic; font-size:10pt; font-weight:bold;" width="100%" colspan="4">094%</td></tr><tr><td style="background:green;" width="70%">&nbsp;</td><td style="background:yellow;" width="20%">&nbsp;</td><td style="background:red;" width="04%">&nbsp;</td><td style="height:10px;" width="006%">&nbsp;</td></tr></table></td><td width="02%">&nbsp;</td><td width="23%"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1"><tr><td style="color:#9400D3; font-style:italic; font-size:10pt; font-weight:bold;" width="100%" colspan="4">Last 15 minutes</td></tr><tr><td style="text-align:center; color:#9400D3; font-style:italic; font-size:10pt; font-weight:bold;" width="100%" colspan="4">084%</td></tr><tr><td style="background:green;" width="70%">&nbsp;</td><td style="background:yellow;" width="14%">&nbsp;</td><td style="height:10px;" width="016%">&nbsp;</td></tr></table></td><td width="02%">&nbsp;</td><td width="23%"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1"><tr><td style="color:#8B008B; font-style:italic; font-size:10pt; font-weight:bold;" width="100%" colspan="4">Last 30 minutes</td></tr><tr><td style="text-align:center; color:#8B008B; font-style:italic; font-size:10pt; font-weight:bold;" width="100%" colspan="4">076%</td></tr><tr><td style="background:green;" width="70%">&nbsp;</td><td style="background:yellow;" width="06%">&nbsp;</td><td style="height:10px;" width="024%">&nbsp;</td></tr></table></td><td width="02%">&nbsp;</td><td width="23%"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1"><tr><td style="color:#9932CC; font-style:italic; font-size:10pt; font-weight:bold;" width="100%" colspan="4">Last 60 minutes</td></tr><tr><td style="text-align:center; color:#9932CC; font-style:italic; font-size:10pt; font-weight:bold;" width="100%" colspan="4">080%</td></tr><tr><td style="background:green;" width="70%">&nbsp;</td><td style="background:yellow;" width="10%">&nbsp;</td><td style="height:10px;" width="020%">&nbsp;</td></tr></table></td><td width="02%">&nbsp;</td></tr></table></div><br><!-- /B/ ftacput3 -->
<br>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="text-align: center; color:#000080; font-weight: bold; font-size: 14pt; background-color:#B0E0E6;" width="100%">AX2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<!-- /E/ ftacput3 -->
<div style="color:#000080; font-size:11pt; font-weight:bold;">CPU usage as of: 10:04</div><table width="80%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr><td style="text-align:center; color:#D2691E; font-style:italic; font-size:14pt; font-weight:bold;" width="100%" colspan="4">031%</td></tr><tr><td style="background:green; height:25px;" width="31%">&nbsp;</td><td style="height:25px;" width="069%">&nbsp;</td></tr></table><br><div><span style="color:#8B4513; font-weight:bold; font-size:11pt;">Recent averages:</span><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1"><tr><td width="23%"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1"><tr><td style="color:#8A2BE2; font-style:italic; font-size:10pt; font-weight:bold;" width="100%" colspan="4">Last 5 minutes </td></tr><tr><td style="text-align:center; color:#8A2BE2; font-style:italic; font-size:10pt; font-weight:bold;" width="100%" colspan="4">031%</td></tr><tr><td style="background:green;" width="31%">&nbsp;</td><td style="height:10px;" width="069%">&nbsp;</td></tr></table></td><td width="02%">&nbsp;</td><td width="23%"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1"><tr><td style="color:#9400D3; font-style:italic; font-size:10pt; font-weight:bold;" width="100%" colspan="4">Last 15 minutes</td></tr><tr><td style="text-align:center; color:#9400D3; font-style:italic; font-size:10pt; font-weight:bold;" width="100%" colspan="4">022%</td></tr><tr><td style="background:green;" width="22%">&nbsp;</td><td style="height:10px;" width="078%">&nbsp;</td></tr></table></td><td width="02%">&nbsp;</td><td width="23%"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1"><tr><td style="color:#8B008B; font-style:italic; font-size:10pt; font-weight:bold;" width="100%" colspan="4">Last 30 minutes</td></tr><tr><td style="text-align:center; color:#8B008B; font-style:italic; font-size:10pt; font-weight:bold;" width="100%" colspan="4">021%</td></tr><tr><td style="background:green;" width="21%">&nbsp;</td><td style="height:10px;" width="079%">&nbsp;</td></tr></table></td><td width="02%">&nbsp;</td><td width="23%"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1"><tr><td style="color:#9932CC; font-style:italic; font-size:10pt; font-weight:bold;" width="100%" colspan="4">Last 60 minutes</td></tr><tr><td style="text-align:center; color:#9932CC; font-style:italic; font-size:10pt; font-weight:bold;" width="100%" colspan="4">037%</td></tr><tr><td style="background:green;" width="37%">&nbsp;</td><td style="height:10px;" width="063%">&nbsp;</td></tr></table></td><td width="02%">&nbsp;</td></tr></table></div><br><!-- /B/ ftacput3 -->
<br>
```

I need to extract values from the above. In here, the first value is 083 and the second value is 031. *I don't know how to highlight the numbers in above, but those will fall in the longest two lines after colspan=4.*

When I'm running the following regex expression, I'm able to get the first match, but how to get the 2nd match?

Or, there might be a different way? This can be tested here. `http://193.138.212.37/SiteScope/cgi/go.exe/SiteScope`

```
/<td style="text-align:center; color:#D2691E; font-style:italic; font-size:14pt; font-weight:bold;" width="100%" colspan="4">(\d+)/
```

Thanks,

Koushik

Comment: Can you trim your html a bit down to the relevant parts? Or is the entire block needed?

Comment: @Gray, the entire block is needed. But, I'm making short and putting the data that I need.

<div style="color:#000080; font-size:11pt; font-weight:bold;">CPU usage as of: 10:05</div><table width="80%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr><td style="text-align:center; color:#D2691E; font-style:italic; font-size:14pt; font-weight:bold;" width="100%" colspan="4">083%

Comment: Is there a way to get the cpu usage directly from the thing reporting it, rather than trying to scrape the web page? In other words, do you have access to that machine? Here is a jsfiddle that I think makes this easier to read. http://jsfiddle.net/LdPYL/1/ May help someone else.

Comment: @Gray - This data comes from a webpage which collates information from multiple sources. I am trying to setup 2 URL monitors in SiteScope that will get only the values of the first 2 systems. Btw, the jsfiddle is a nice one, have not used it before.